# Cannot create a table in MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I came across a simple question but I don't know why.
The first SQL could create the table, The second can't. why?

```
String temString = "create table if not exists test(number int not null, name varchar(20) not null, primary key(number))engine=myisam default charset=utf8";
String createTableString = "create table if not exists ju_users (ju_userID int not null, TaobaoID int not null, ju_userName varchar(20) not null, ju_userPWD varchar(10) not null, primary key (ju_userID)) engine=myisam defalut charset=utf8";
```

the message is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'defalut charset=utf8' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at mysql_test.Main.CreateTable(Main.java:132)
    at mysql_test.Main.main(Main.java:159)
```

I just want to set the engine of the table...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What DB are you using (mySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc)?

Comment: wasn't the error message explicit enough here?

Comment: **defalut charset=utf8** should be **default charset=utf8**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled default.

Instead of:

```
defalut charset=utf8"
```

Your query should end with

```
default charset=utf8"
```

Comment: You done great job. Yeah because of that it gives an error.

Comment: Welcome david zhao...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because there is no space after "test" (your second table name)?

I'm actually surprised the first one works because you misspelled "default" too.

Tried to **bold** the text in each to make it super obvious but bold doesn't work in blockquotes or code samples, sorry!

Comment: Yep, pretty much sure it's the misspelled "default" based on the error code now, but "test(" will cause you problems too.